# Intersection of a median of a triangle with another line segment

Tags: geometry, triangles

In triangle *ABC*, **M** is the midpoint of **|BC|** and **D** is the interior point of **|AB|**. Point **E** is the intersection of the sides **|AM|** and **|CD|**. Prove that if **|AD| = |DE**|, then **|AB| = |CE|**.

I know that this is true for medians, but this should apply to all, I think.

Comment: Oh, I see. When you say "$D$ is the interior point of $|AB|$, I think you just mean $D$ is a point on segment $AB$, in which case your answer is correct.

I assumed at first (like user45195), that you meant interior point of $\triangle ABC$, in which case of course the statement is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

If | AD | = | DE | => | AB | = | CE |.

Suppose | AD | = | DE |, denoted | AD | = x

P || AB, M∈p

ΔAED is similar ΔMFG

F∈ p∩DC

Point F is the midpoint of the segment DC, since p is a line on the middle rung ΔDBC

FM - middle rung ΔDBC

| BD | = 2 | FM |

| BD | = 2y

| AB | = | AD | + | BD | = x + 2y

| EC | = | EF | + | FC | = y + x + y = x + 2y

So Page | AB | = | EC |

If | AD | = | DE | => | AB | = | CE |.

I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears wrong. Suppose $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle of side 1 unit and $AD=DE=\frac12unit$. Just because $AD=DE$, it doesn't mean $AB=CE$ (as $AB=1$ and $CE=CD-DE=\frac{\sqrt5}{2}-\frac12$